# Await task on application exit

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an app where it records video. So far so good, but if the user exits the app (X button or Alt + F4 or w/e) the video get corrupted (saved in chunks). Is there an event where I can capture such closing event and `await a Task` to finish? I've tried `Application.Current.Dispatcher.ShutdownStarted` and **it works** for small videos, but I'm not sure if its reliable since the video can be really long. The app gets closed immediately, but I'm not sure if still awaits the `Task` in the background and that could be the reason why it works.

Advice?

Comment: You better prompt the user... Let the user know that the video will be corrupt if they close the app.  Then allow them to cancel and wait until the video is done.

Comment: Typically you would handle the [`Window.Closing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.closing?view=netframework-4.8) event and ask the user if they really want to close while the recording is active, and if they don't cancel the event. If they do, shut the recording down and continue shutting down. This works if the user presses ALT-F4 as well. You also want to handle [`SessionEnding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.sessionending?view=netframework-4.8) in case of shut down or log-off.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle the `Closing` event for your window, cancel the closing by setting the `Cancel` property of the `CancelEventArgs` to `true` and then explicitly await your task and call `Close()` on the window once the task has completed:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Closing += MainWindow_Closing;
}

private bool _doClose = false;
private async void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_doClose)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        await ClosingTasks();
    }
}

private async Task ClosingTasks()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000); //await your task here...
    _doClose = true;
    Close();
}
```